# random change of position or scale in the collection using geometry nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, collections, fcurves, random

I have candles arranged in three curves and I need to be able to make an animation of the appearance by position or scale randomly for each candle[image]

Comment: did you try to plugin random value node into rotation? did you try plugin random value node in offset of set position node?

Comment: yes, it didn’t help, it separates the collection separately, candle, fire, wick, and I need to shift the whole candle randomly

Comment: Did u uncheck separate children?

Comment: To be honest, might sound hard: u should watch a beginner tutorial for geometry nodes. This is an absolute basic question and not so hard to solve.

Comment: I have been looking for solutions for a long time, but I did not find anything similar. I suspect that it is necessary to somehow change the position of each point using the index, but it does not work.